# wxPython, crash on import

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have Python3 and wxPython (phoenix) installed, however when I try to run this program from the command line (windows) I get "Import Error: no module named 'wx'"

```
import wx

eliminare = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'Elimina scheda', 'Scegliere una scheda da eliminare',
                                       ['ciao','b'])
if eliminare.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
    elimina = eliminare.GetStringSelection()
```

However, if in the command line I run

```
python
>>>import wx
```

it works fine. But if I try:

```
python
>>>import wx
>>>eliminare = wx.SingleChoiceDialog(None, 'aaa', ['a','b'])
```

Windows gives me the message "Python has stopped working". What is going on?

Comment: Maybe you have two Pythons and you use different python when you run from file and when you run `python`.

Comment: @Nadmi, can you copy and the whole python session? it should give a backtrace at the end

Comment: Most wxPython widgets require an app object to be instantiated before they will work. Without the main loop, most widgets won't work, so trying to run wxPython in the interpreter usually won't work either.